# How to fix the Prisma vulnerability created by json2xls

Tags: node.js, security, npm, prisma, npm-vulnerabilities

I am using json2xls v0.1.2 package, Its is creating Prisma vulnerability, is there any way that i can fix it? npm audit result is as below.

```
                           === npm audit security report ===
    
    
                                     Manual Review
                 Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve
    
              Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
    
    
      Moderate   Prototype Pollution
    
      Package         jszip
    
      Patched in      >=3.7.0
    
      Dependency of   json2xls
    
      Path            json2xls > excel-export > node-zip > jszip
    
      More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jg8v-48h5-wgxg
    
    found 1 moderate severity vulnerability in 937 scanned packages
      1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of the `json2xls` package needs to upgrade the dependencies to fix these vulnerabilities.

You can create a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rikkertkoppes/json2xls/issues) on its official repository to report this and request the dependencies to be upgraded. However, this package has not been maintained for the last 6 years so I won't be expecting an early response from the maintainer. I would recommend looking for an alternative package if available.